# jquery and classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-widgets

I have 2 classes:

```
$.widget('blueimp.fileupload', {
    a: function  {}
})

$.widget('blueimpUI.fileupload', $.blueimp.fileupload, {
    b: function  {}
})
```

I want to replace my first two functions with a single class.

Function `b` works but function `a` doesn't. Why?

```
$.widget('blueimpUI.fileupload', $.blueimpUI.fileupload, {
    a: function  {},
    b: function  {}
})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this might work better:

```
$.widget('blueimpUI.fileupload', {
    fileupload: $.blueimp.fileupload, 
    a: function  {},
    b: function  {}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear what you're trying to do but I believe the `$.widget` method takes two arguments as explained in [this documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI_Developer_Guide#The_widget_factory):

> jquery.ui.widget.js provides a factory method to create widget
>   classes. The signature is $.widget(String name, Options prototype)

Therefore, the code with function b probably does not work due to incorrect syntax.